# Most efficient/fastest way to delete/remove items of a vector

Tags: c++

There are several ways to delete/remove items of a vector.

I have a vector of pointers and I need to delete all of them on the deconstructor of the class.

What is the most efficient/fastest way or even safest way?

```
// 1º
std::for_each(vector.begin(), vector.end(), [] (Object * object) {
    delete object;
});

// 2º
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i)
{
    delete vector[i];
}

// 3º
for (auto current = vector.begin(); current != vector.end(); ++current){
    delete (* current);
}
```

Comment: This "problem" would be moot if you used smart pointers instead.

Comment: where is recursively?

Comment: this questions seems to be a duplicate of "what is the quickest way to iterate through a vector?"

Comment: None of these pieces of code removes items of a vector.

Comment: In C++11: `for(auto ptr : vector) delete ptr;`. But seriously, use `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way would be to use either `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>` depending on the lifetime semantics you need for the `Object` instances.

Either way, you wouldn't need to do *anything* in the destructor; the vector's destructor will destruct all of the smart pointer instances.  In turn, they would automatically delete the `Object` instances according to their particular semantics: `unique_ptr` would delete them immediately, while `shared_ptr` would delete them as soon as no other `shared_ptr`s point to that object.

It's very unlikely that there will be a faster way either, assuming that you need to store pointers. (If you don't need polymorphism, then you could just use `std::vector<Object>` which has one less level of indirection.)